# How to hide .jsp extension with web.xml

Tags: jsp, tomcat

When I tried this code it shows error and stop executing the code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/WebApplication1"/>


<servlet>
<servlet-name>company</servlet-name>
<jsp-file>/companyDashboard.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>company</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/companyDashboard</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a mapping in your web.xml

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>thejsp</servlet-name>
  <jsp-file>/thejsp.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>thejsp</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/thejsp</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```